# if $\cos^{10}x + \sin^{10}x=11/36$, find $\cos^{12}x+\sin^{12}x$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\cos^{10}x+ \sin^{10}x=11/36$, find $\cos^{12}x+\sin^{12}x$. I've tried solving using index manipulation but no way. I think we're to use $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$. But I don't know how. Need help please.

Comment: This is from AIME 2019, no? There are some answers on AoPS [here](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Ccos%5E%7B10%7Dx%20%2B%20%5Csin%5E%7B10%7Dx%3D11%2F36%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Ccos%5E%7B12%7Dx%2B%5Csin%5E%7B12%7Dx%24&p=1).

Comment: A brute force approach: $$
\cos ^{10} x + \sin ^{10} x = (\cos ^2 x)^5  + (1 - \cos ^2 x)^5  = \frac{{11}}{{36}} \Rightarrow \cos ^2 x = \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{{\sqrt 3 }}{6}.
$$ Then $$\cos ^{12} x + \sin ^{12} x = (\cos ^2 x)^6  + (1 - \cos ^2 x)^6  = \left( {\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{{\sqrt 3 }}{6}} \right)^6  + \left( {\frac{1}{2} \mp \frac{{\sqrt 3 }}{6}} \right)^6  = \frac{{13}}{{54}}.
$$

Comment: @Gary how did you solve the biquadratic ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus With $z=\cos^2 x$, the equation we have to solve is $$
0=5z^4  - 10z^3  + 10z^2  - 5z + \frac{{25}}{{36}} = 5\!\left( {z^2  - z + \tfrac{1}{6}} \right)\left( {z^2  - z + \tfrac{5}{6}} \right).
$$ Only the first factor has real roots. The result you got below is different from mine though.

Comment: @Gary Yes, I know, but I dont see any error in my work.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution. Let $A=\sin^2 x\cos^2 x$
$$\sin^4+\cos^4=\sin^2+\cos^2-2\sin^2 x\cos^2 x=1-2A$$
$$\sin^6+\cos^6=\sin^4+\cos^4-A(\sin^2 +\cos^2 x)=1-3A$$
$$\sin^8+\cos^8=\sin^6+\cos^6-A(\sin^4 +\cos^4 x)=1-4A+2A^2$$
$$\sin^{10}+\cos^{10}=\sin^8+\cos^8-A(\sin^6 +\cos^6 x)$$
$$=1-5A+5A^2$$

Thus we have $$5A^2-5A+1=\frac{11}{36}$$
Which gives $$A=\frac{1}{6}$$ using the fact that $A\leq \frac{1}{4}$
So finally
$$\sin^{12}+\cos^{12}=\sin^{10}+\cos^{10}-A(\sin^8 +\cos^8 x)$$
$$=1-6A+9A^2-2A^3=\frac{13}{54}$$

Hope I havent made a mistake.

Comment: I got $1 - 6A + 9A^2  - 2A^3$ for $\sin^{12} x+\cos^{12} x$.

Comment: @Gary Thanks for that now I get your answer. You should put your solution as an answer.